# Read service response(json format) inside xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Need to read a service response inside xslt which is of format :

> servicedata={"statusCode":200,"loginMessage":"Welcome User"}

its key value pair, where i can get the value of 'servicedata' but further need to get the status code value for some condition checking.

Using version 2.0 for the xslt

read few questions which suggested to use parse-json(), json-to-xml with 3.0 version of xslt, but didn't help.

Question: first using version 2.0 only can I retrieve the value for the 'statusCode' and how, if not guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: Well, which XSLT 2.0 processor exactly do you use? If it is a recent version of Altova or of Saxon then using those functions you mention should be possible and should help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using Saxon-HE 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can move to Saxon 9.7 HE then you could use `json-to-xml` as follows for instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="data">

        <xsl:value-of select="json-to-xml(substring-after(., 'servicedata='))//*[@key = 'statusCode']" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which for the input

```
<data>servicedata={"statusCode":200,"loginMessage":"Welcome User"}</data>
```

outputs `200`.

I have not checked whether earlier versions of Saxon 9 also support that.

Comment: I have converted into Saxon 9.7 HE, now after maven clean install I am getting error for net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem, is this class deprecated in 9.7?

Comment: I am able to run the code I posted fine with Saxon 9.7 HE inside Oxygen 19 and outside of Oxygen from the command line. Do you have problems running Saxon 9.7 at all or just with my suggested code? In any way, if the problem is related to running Saxon with Java, it is better if you post a new question, explaining and showing all the details of your code and tagging the question for saxon so that Saxonica/Michael Kay can help.

Comment: In Saxon 9.7, there is no class found net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem which is used in our project(9.5). So I am searching for alternate class of net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem in 9.5

Comment: As I said, if it is a problem using the Saxon API with Java when moving forward to a current release, then it is better asking that as a separate question tagged with Java and Saxon here on Stackoverflow or directly in their help forum https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/boards/3, I am sure you will get advice from them.